# I need this jquery/ajax script to run every 30 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Now I have been puzzling with this for some time.
I got part of it together in jquery/ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sessioncheck.php",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(response){
            if (response) {
                window.location.href = 'logout.php';
            }
            else {
                // Process the expected results...
            }
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

This works perfectly, but I would like this process to repeat itself every 30 seconds.
Can someone please help me with that? I have read something about setinterval, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Thanks a lot in advance for all of your help!

Comment: why? If you're doing session management, the server should already be able to take care of this by comparing last-active times on the session, you don't need the client to ping the server every X seconds.

Comment: Because if they login from another location, I want the old session to log off automatically. In other words, they can then only be logged in once.

Comment: If it is important, you should do that server-side as javascript is easily disabled.

Comment: The site serves with streams and without javascript the stream will not load. So that isn't really a problem.

It would be better to do this server side though, but I can't think of a way to do that..

Answer (score 10):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sessioncheck.php",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(response){
                if (response) {
                    window.location.href = 'logout.php';
                }
                else {
                    // Process the expected results...
                }
            }

        });
    }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this method will initiate the request every 30 seconds, but the responses may be delayed or even returned out of order.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins If the server takes more than 30 seconds to respond to this, he probably has bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Then just cancel the previous request on the next iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Add a interval like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sessioncheck.php",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(response){
                if (response) {
                    window.location.href = 'logout.php';
                }
                else {
                    // Process the expected results...
                }
            }
        });
    }, 30000);
});
</script>
```

More info here: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/

Answer (score 2):

Just do a setInterval...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sessioncheck.php",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(response){
            if (response) {
                window.location.href = 'logout.php';
            }
            else {
                // Process the expected results...
              }
           }
        });
    }, 30000);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: rats....man Im so slow at typing...lol

Comment: This will only run once in 30 seconds... not every 30 seconds